# Cast object reference to real object

Tags: java, string, object, casting, reference

I'm requesting something from a database, as a result i get the following object:

"[Ljava.lang.Object;@64a294a6"

What is that? Can I do anything useful with that and convert it into something else?

```
        // FIXME
    List singleTasks = Arrays.asList((Object[]) objClient.execute("execute_kw",
            Arrays.asList(db, uid, password, "project.task", "search_read",
                    Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList(
                            Arrays.asList("active", "=", true))),
                    new HashMap() {{
                        put("fields", Arrays.asList("display_name", "total_hours", "project_id", "user_id"));
                        HashMap map = this;
                        System.out.println(map.get("fields"));
                    }}
                )));

    HashMap map = (HashMap)singleTasks.get(0);
    System.out.println(map.get("project_id").getClass().getName());
```

getClass.getName only gives me: "[Ljava.lang.Object;" as result.

Comment: If you selecting anything from the DB you should know what it is

Comment: Please add a sample code.

Comment: Add something like:
System.out.println(yourResultObject.getClass().getName());
to get the Type of the Result

Comment: `[Ljava.lang.Object;` means `Object[]`. If you want to see values in the array, do what the answer in the duplicate link says.